# Recaptcha v2 em servidor local!

Tags: .net, localhost, recaptcha

Antes de tudo, caso essa pergunta não se encaixe aqui não precisa negativar só falar que eu removo. Mas enfim, acredito que todos nos programadores já passamos por esse problema, não consegui testar o recaptcha do google no localhost, apenas em domínios na web. Portanto estava pensando, deve haver um jeito! Alguém saberia me dizer se existe realmente essa possibilidade? 
Porque estou tendo uma grande mão de obra aqui com uma aplicação que estou fazendo em .NET por conta disso, tenho que ficar upando a todo momento na web para testar as configurações pois no meu localhost não consigo visualizar!

Comment: Basta acessar as configurações da sua página do ReCAPTCHA e incluir o localhost nos domínios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com o [recaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/domain_validation)  qualquer chave é válida apontando para localhost ou 127.0.0.1 dentro de sua aplicação.
 Caso voce utilize outro caminho para testar seu ambiente você pode criar uma nova aplicação e inserir seu url para testes, assim voce terá uma chave para produção e uma chave para homologação.

Comment: Mais como eu passo isso la quando crio a chave, pois ele não não aceita o endereço e IP ou o nome Localhost???

Comment: Coloquei localhost aqui na whitelist e aceitou! Valeu man!